# how to avoid remote code execution in webview appcelerator?

Tags: security, webview, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

My app not pass in pentest because my webview is no security.
They return this info "Remote Code Execution em WebView RCE - CVE-2013-4710".

I need information for resolve this problem and distribute my app.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVE-2013-4710 is a vulnerability in WebView, you can find the issue here: https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4710/ it looks like it affects really old versions of Android (3.x - 4.x) and the current version is 10.x. From what I can gather, the fix is to not use an old version of Android. If your app is using a new version of Android, then this might be a false positive in the tool used to scan your app. What tool said you had the issue?